# Editing imported CI/CD job properties without overwriting completely

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm currently working with a large CI/CD package which is imported into my project, and I'd like to make small adjustments to the existing jobs. I've currently got this setup:

```yaml
include:
  - project: "some-project"
    ref: master
    file: "some-project/.gitlab-ci.yml"

deploy_to_dev:
  before_script:
    - echo "This should happen at the very beginning"
```

where `deploy_to_dev` is an already existing defined job from the included project. The script above works okay, but it completely overwrites the previous items that were already in `deploy_to_dev:before_script`. Is there any way to "append" items at the beginning or end of these properties without completely overwriting/replacing them? I'm imagining something like:

```yaml
deploy_to_dev:
  before_script:
    - echo "This should happen at the very beginning"

    # keep things that were already in before_script
    - ...[deploy_to_dev:before_script]
```

If possible, I'd prefer to not make any changes to the included project. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's no builtin way to do this. Normally, that's the reason why `before_script:` and `script:` exist as separate keys to begin with. Of course, some use cases need even more levels of flexibility.

Without modifying the included project, there is a workaround. You can create a new job and use `!reference` to 'merge' array items.

```yaml
# ...
deploy_to_dev:
  rules: # don't actually run the included job
    - when: never

custom_deploy_to_dev: # create a new job that extends the original
  extends: deploy_to_dev
  rules:
    - when: on_success
  before_script:  # use !reference to "append" to before_script
    - 'echo "prepended action"'
    - !reference [deploy_to_dev, before_script]
    - 'echo "appended action"'
  # ...
```

If you control the included project, you can of course just script in this flexibility. For example, allowing users to define user 'hook' scripts to run at predetermined points in the job.

Comment: This is in the right direction, +1, but if your imported jobs has detailed rules then you'd overwrite them with `when: on_success` here. I.e. you'd have to duplicate the rules `deploy_to_dev` had into `custom_deploy_to_dev`. Any way to avoid removing this information?